# How can I Freeze a null instance in AutoFixture

Tags: autofixture

I'm using Autofixture as a SUT factory and am having difficulty Freezing null instances.

I'd like to do something like:

```
_fixture.Freeze<IPayPalConfiguration>(c => null);
```

but quickly realized that was wrong.  I've worked around the problem using this:

```
_fixture.Inject((IMyInterface)null);
```

but it doesn't seem right.

Hopefully someone will contribute the correct solution to the HiveMind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, `Freeze` creates an instance of the requested type (e.g. `IPayPalConfiguration`) and then *injects* it so it will always return that instance when you request it again.

In that particular case, by doing `_fixture.Inject((IPayPalConfiguration)null)` you inject the null reference manually so you skip the creation part of the `Freeze` method. You *freeze* the `IPayPalConfiguration` to a single value (actually, a null reference here) but in a manual way.

Keep in mind that this `_fixture.Freeze<IPayPalConfiguration>(c => null)` passes a null reference for the *method* that will try to resolve the `IPayPalConfiguration` and for that reason an ArgumentNullException is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and at least confirmation that I am not doing the wrong thing