# Can't grasp the difference between Freeze/Inject/Register

Tags: c#, autofixture

Before starting, I'm a big fan of AutoFixture, I'm still in the curve of learning how to use the tool. So thanks for having developed Autofixture Mr Ploeh and all the contributors.

So let's start with my question.

According to
[AutoFixture/AutoMoq ignores injected instance/frozen mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484471/autofixture-automoq-ignores-injected-instance-frozen-mock)

The interesting part of the above link is given this code

```
Mock<ISettings> settingsMock = new Mock<ISettings>();
settingsMock.Setup(s => s.Get(settingKey)).Returns(xmlString);

ISettings settings = settingsMock.Object;
fixture.Inject(settings);
```

To which Mark answer it can be rewritten to

```
fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISettings>>()
       .Setup(s => s.Get(settingKey)).Returns(xmlString);
```

It looks like a syntaxic sugar, using Freeze method is a way to write in fluent interface the creation of the mock, the configuration, and the injection in autofixture container.

After doing some research on the web, there're actually a functional difference between Freeze and Inject. I found this question:
https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/59
which point the answer to 
[How can I Freeze a null instance in AutoFixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218206/how-can-i-freeze-a-null-instance-in-autofixture/12219355#12219355)

The author of the link above describe Freeze method as the following:

> Internally, Freeze creates an instance of the requested type (e.g.
>   IPayPalConfiguration) and then injects it so it will always return
>   that instance when you request it again

I understand that when we do

```
var customer = fixture.Freeze<Order>();
```

it will always use the same instance of Order whenever our code request an Order type. But what if I specify in Freeze constructor that I want it to use a specific instance ?

Here's a little code example:

```
[Fact]
public void MethodeName()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    fixture.Freeze<OrderLine>(new OrderLine("Foo"));
    var order = fixture.Create<Order>();
}

public class Order
{
    private readonly OrderLine _line;

    public Order(OrderLine line)
    {
        _line = line;
    }
}
public class OrderLine
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public OrderLine(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the name of OrderLine be equal to "Foo" instead of namefe48163a-d5a0-49a5-b349-7b11ba5f804b ? The documentation of Freeze method say:

```
<typeparam name="T">The type to freeze.</typeparam>
<param name="fixture">The fixture.</param>
<param name="seed">Any data that adds additional information when creating the anonymous object. Hypothetically, this value might be the value being frozen, but this is not likely.</param>
```

why is the author not sure when the value is returned ? If I specify, my instance in the constructor of Freeze, I'm expecting autofixture to use this instance ?

then

> Please notice that the  isn't likely to be used as the frozen value, unless you've customized  to do this. If you wish to inject a specific value into the Fixture, you should use the  method instead.`

It seems like I have to customize the seed parameter. Can anyone clarify ? The solution pointed by documentation is to use Inject method. And indeed, it works in my code example with OrderLine.

I'm looking for your help to understand the difference between Freeze, Inject, and also Register which, according to the source code, is just called by Inject method but it takes a lambda.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Register and Inject**

Once upon a time, there was no `Inject` and no `Freeze`; `Register` ruled the code.

Back then, there was a `Register` overload defined thusly:

```
public static void Register<T>(this IFixture fixture, T item)
```

However, it had to share the API with this close relative:

```
public static void Register<T>(this IFixture fixture, Func<T> creator)
```

The creator of AutoFixture thought that this was good, but alas: users were stricken with confusion. Most grievously, a user could write:

```
fixture.Register(() => universe.LightUp());
```

but also

```
fixture.Register(universe.LightUp);
```

which means the exact same thing, because `universe.LightUp` is a reference to a method, and thus matches a delegate.

However, that syntax looks like a property reference, so if `LightUp` had been a property instead of a method, the first overload would be selected by the compiler.

This caused much confusion, so the `Register<T>(this IFixture fixture, T item)` overload was renamed to `Inject<T>(this IFixture fixture, T item)`.

**Freeze**

Freeze has a different history. A long time ago, when I still used AutoFixture in an imperative way, I noticed that I repeatedly wrote code like this:

```
var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
fixture.Inject(foo);
```

So I decided that this was a concept and named it *Freeze*. The `Freeze` method is only shorthand for those two lines of code.

> I'm looking for your help to understand the difference between Freeze, Inject, and also Register which, according to the source code, is just called by Inject method but it takes a lambda

In general, it shouldn't be too hard to distinguish between `Inject` and `Register`, since their signatures don't collide. Thus, if you try to accomplish a goal with one of those two methods, and your code compiles, you probably chose the right version.

This would also be the case for `Freeze` if it wasn't for the overload used in the OP:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public static T Freeze<T>(this IFixture fixture, T seed)
```

Notice that this overload actually has `EditorBrowsableState.Never`, because it always confuses people. However, despite that, apparently people still find that overload, so I think [it should be moved in AutoFixture 4](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/151). It's one of those features that exist because it was easy to implement...

Comment: btw. one reason that this overload is still being found may be the fact that ReSharper appears to be set to ignore the `EditorBrowsable` attribute by default.

Comment: FWIW, in AutoFixture, I plan to move (or take away) the seed overloads away: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/151

Comment: This doesn't really explain the purpose behind these methods, ie., use cases

Comment: If I have a class and an interface, I try something like that and do not work `fixture.Freeze<MyClass>().As<MyInterface>();`... maybe the only solution is `fixture.Register<MyInterface>(() => fixture.Create<MyClass>());`

Answer (score 21):

`Freeze`, `Inject`, and `Register` all are customizing the creation algorithm.

With `Inject` and `Register` you are specifying *explicitly* that an object should be created in a  particular way, in your example by supplying `new OrderLine("Foo")` manually.

With `Freeze` you are not specifying *how* an object should be created - you ask AutoFixture to supply an instance for you.

In the end, all the above methods use the same lower-level API:

`fixture.Customize<T>(c => c.FromFactory(creator).OmitAutoProperties());`

---

The reason why `fixture.Freeze<OrderLine>(new OrderLine("Foo"));` does not create an `OrderLine` instance with the specified seed value is because [by default the seed is ignored](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/DefaultRelays.cs#L32).

To favor seed values of a particular type, you can create a `SeedFavoringRelay<T>`:

```
public class SeedFavoringRelay<T> : ISpecimenBuilder where T : class
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var seededRequest = request as SeededRequest;
        if (seededRequest == null || !seededRequest.Request.Equals(typeof(T)))
            return new NoSpecimen(request);

        var seed = seededRequest.Seed as T;
        if (seed == null)
            return new NoSpecimen(request);

        return seed;
    }
}
```

Then you may use it as below:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new SeedFavoringRelay<OrderLine>());

fixture.Freeze<OrderLine>(new OrderLine("Foo"));
// -> Now fixture.Create<Order>() creates an Order with OrderLine's Name = "Foo".
```

Comment: 1 - ok then why the following code:

Mock<ISettings> settingsMock = new Mock<ISettings>();
settingsMock.Setup(s => s.Get(settingKey)).Returns(xmlString);
fixture.Inject(settingsMock.Object);

is the same as 
fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISettings>>().Setup(s => s.Get(settingKey)).Returns(xmlString);

According to your explanation, I'm just telling autofixture to create a Mock<ISettings> when someone need an instance of ISettings, but the setup part and returns part is outside of the Freeze part. So how comes it's also frozen ?

Comment: 3 - When should I use Inject and Register ? If AutoFixture proposes these two public methods, I guess there're must have situations where one works better than the other.

Comment: As I have read in [these Autofixture-related blog entries](http://blog.ploeh.dk/tags.html#AutoFixture-ref), the `Freeze` method returns the same instance of T whenever/wherever the particular instance of your `Fixture` needs T to build any object. These articles have been a great resource for me.

Comment: `Freeze<T>` returns the created instance of `T` that's why you may continue with setting up expectations on the Mock (as in your example). As for `Inject` vs `Register`, it depends on your needs which is basically passing an instance of `T` vs passing a delegate which, once invoked,  returns an instance of `T`. Technically you will get the same results.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis thanks for your answer, things going clearer in my mind. I created a example to put in practice your explanation, but the result of my test doesn't looks like what it should be. I uploaded my test on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ehy4y4rD can you explain why my test don't pass ? I froze a mock object, and because it returns the instance of T, I should be able to apply the setup as you said but the result is [Expected: Foo] [Actual:   ].  But if I created an interface for my MyWebRequest object, then the code passes. I don't understand why.

Comment: In your example, `MyWebRequest` is a concrete type so AutoFixture does not use Moq to create a mocked instance. To pass the test, refactor `MyService` class to use an `IMyWebRequest` interface and *freeze* a `Mock<IMyWebRequest>` instead. The modified version of the pastebin can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/dZktMUck).

Answer (score 1):

I modified your test (which doesn't assert anything currently, BTW) and if you step through its execution, you'll see an `OrderLine` with "Foo" as its private _line member value is injected into `Order`.

I had another version of the test where I added readonly properties for `OrderLine` in `Order` and `Name` in `OrderLine` so that you could make assertions about these objects, but that's neither here nor there.

This test sets up the fixture using the `FromFactory` method directly, which may be helpful sometimes:

```cs
[Fact]
public void MethodName()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    const string expected = "Foo";
    fixture.Customize<OrderLine>(o => o
        .FromFactory(() =>
            new OrderLine(expected)));
    var order = fixture.Create<Order>();
}
```