# Freeze enum value in AutoFixture

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

We have an enum:

```
enum Letters
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E        
}
```

When I try:

```
var frozenLetter = fixture.Freeze(Letters.D);
```

Strangely, frozenLetter == A.

```
var letter = fixture.Create<Letters>();
var anotherLetter = fixture.Create<Letters>();
```

Letter and anotherLetter both equal A, so the Letters type has been frozen, but to the first constant in the enum rather than the one specified.

Is there a way to freeze an enum to the constant I wish?

Comment: I might be missing something, but what does the Freeze method do?

Comment: It "freezes" the type so that it always returns the same instance whenever an instance of that type is requested. See [AutoFixture Freeze](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze/) by Mark Seeman, AutoFixture's author.

Comment: Hm, looks like [enums are not supported](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/1744) by AutoFixture. As a workaround you could declare a constant (`private const Letters constLetter = Letters.D;`) at the top of your class and use that instead of creating enums with AutoFixture.

Comment: They are now: see [EnumGenerator.cs](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/EnumGenerator.cs). That would be a simple work-around but an instance of Letters is created indirectly a nested value of other types.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Please note that the very resource you link to explicitly states that the issue was *fixed in July 2010!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Freeze` `Inject` and `Register` [are slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161127/autofixture-cant-grasp-the-difference-between-freeze-inject-register).

Use `Inject` for the described behavior, as the following test demonstrates:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var expected = Letters.D;
    fixture.Inject(expected);

    var letter = fixture.Create<Letters>();
    var anotherLetter = fixture.Create<Letters>();

    Assert.Equal(expected, letter);
    Assert.Equal(expected, anotherLetter);
}
```

The problem with the question's sample code is that the parameter *(seed)* [isn't used as the frozen value](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/FixtureFreezer.cs#L43-74).

Comment: Aha, classic mistake there. Thanks for the clear explanation.